# Azure DevOps: Fill 'Azure subscription' field using variables

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a question regarding Azure DevOps, It seems it is not possible to set in pipeline's jobs `Azure subscription` field using variables. On attempt to do this I'm getting the error message:

> The pipeline is not valid.

I was trying to use in variable:

- Subscription ID
- Service Connection Name
- Service Connection ID

But with no luck - the same issue again and again. Since I need to change subscriptions for pipeline very often, it's very critical problem for me. Could you please elaborate the issue?

Comment: It's possible; I do it frequently. Are you using YAML pipelines or visual designer JSON pipelines?

Comment: I'm using visual designer JSON pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

If you use YAML pipelines you could configure your subscription as variable as follows:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(SubscriptionId)'
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      az --version
      az account show
```

[Variable settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH5XH.png)

And during every build you can override your azure subscription.

Comment: thank you for proposed solution, how is it possible to transfer the value of $(SubscriptionID) to Release pipeline then? Or it will be changed globally?

Comment: You can use variable groups to transfer values between different pipelines.

Unfortunately, I was unable to use variable $(SubscriptionId) to set Subscription value in JSON editor (classic editor). 

I was also trying to follow steps from two posts, but I wasn't able to parametrize value of Subscription ID. https://blog.rassie.dk/2018/10/modifying-azure-devops-release-pipeline-parameters/
http://blog.repsaj.nl/index.php/2018/04/vsts-using-process-parameters-in-release-definitions/

It looks like in JSON editory service connection is valued as GUID, but in YAML editor it's as string.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It will fail with an error similar to `The pipeline is not valid. Job down: Step AzureCLI input connectedServiceNameARM references service connection $(SubscriptionId) which could not be found.`

See https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/12605 for more info